# filter data.table for !is.na()

Tags: r, data.table

As far as I know it should be avoided to use "&" and "|" in i to avoid vector scans. Therefore:

```
data<-data.table(a=c(NA, 1, 2), b=c(1, 2, 1), key="a,b")
data[is.na(a) & b==1]
```

should be replaced by

```
data[.(NA_integer_, 1)]
```

But: When I'm interesed in all non-NA entries how should I do that? Is this ok to use the following or does it use slower vector scans?

```
data[!is.na(a) & b==1]
```

because something like this does not seem to work

```
data[.(!NA_integer_, 1)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to have expressions of the form you require in binary search based subsets currently.. i.e., we can not *negate* on individual key columns.

The way to perform a binary search based subset at the moment would be:

```
require(data.table) ## v1.9.5+
a_val = setdiff(unique(data$a), NA)
setkey(data)[.(a_val, 1), nomatch=0L]
#    a b
# 1: 2 1
```

May be it'd be nice to have a function, for example, `not()` or `except()` that'd allow us to extract the values internally... care to file a FR [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues)?